# Discord.py check member status

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to write a chunk of code for my discord bot that announces when one of my friend's profile status updates from offline to online.

Currently, I am fiddling around with some code, this is what I have so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after)
    if str(before.status) == "offline":
        if str(after.status) == "online":
            await message.channel.send(f"""{} is now {}""".format(after.name,after.status))
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Aghgh the formatting didnt work great, please imagine proper indentations after every colon.

Comment: Tip: You can edit your question by clicking the *edit* button below the question

Answer (score 3):

You have to compare both status. then send a message to a channel using its `id`

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.status is discord.Status.offline and after.status is discord.Status.online:
        print('was offline then online')
        channel = client.get_channel(ID_HERE)  # notification channel
        await channel.send(f'{after.name} is now {after.status}')
```

Docs:

[`discord.Status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.htmlhighlight=status#discord.Status)

Comment: I have tried this out and cant seem to get it working :(
Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It should be working as is, What is the error you are getting? remember this from the docs [`This requires Intents.members to be enabled.`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update)

Comment: Yes I looked into it and needed to change the intents. Thank you !

Comment: Glad it worked, Please mark it as an answer if so.