# How to detect user presence(online,offline) in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

anyone have an idea how to detect when a user goes offline and remove a role. This is for a bot that i am making with discord.py version 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

isn't there a role already like that? @here should be what you're trying to do.

I haven't used Discord.py at all so I can't give you an in depth explanation, but maybe this is a direction you can go to

Also maybe have a look at this:

[Discord.py check member status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101859/discord-py-check-member-status)

Sorry can't comment because of rep

Comment: this doesn't work tho